# Vue directives how to 100% ensure component is in document

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

**Hook Functions A directive definition object can provide several hook functions (all optional):**

> **bind**: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the
>   element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.
>
> **inserted**: called when the bound element has been inserted into its
>   parent node (this only guarantees parent node presence, not
>   necessarily in-document).
>
> **update**: called after the containing component’s VNode has updated, but
>   possibly before its children have updated. The directive’s value may
>   or may not have changed, but you can skip unnecessary updates by
>   comparing the binding’s current and old values (see below on hook
>   arguments).
>
> **componentUpdated**: called after the containing component’s VNode and
>   the VNodes of its children have updated.
>
> **unbind**: called only once, when the directive is unbound from the
>   element.

None of these hooks guarantee the component is **in document**. `Inserted` works but has the potential to fail it seems?

How do you ensure the component is truly in the document?

Answer (score 0):

```js
{
  inserted: function (el) {
    document.contains(el) // true if element already exist in document
  },
}
```

Hope it help's

Comment: sure .. you can just do this too `if (el) {}` too but not really my point - looking for a hook. See the issue is inserted can be called and DOM doesn't contain the el yet. Now I need to queue this directive binding and re-attempt it on a interval to ensure my fn gets called.